# What service can I use to host multiple wordpress sites for multiple customers

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to start selling websites by being able to generate clean WP installations without having to worry about the server side.

I there a service that is optimal for this?

I want to easily be able to create clean WP installations and start workign on building websites for my customers maybe even create a woocommerce stores, I'm mostly concerned about finding a platform that allows me to easily manage this and in a way I can charge customers a predictable price and limit storage usage or traffic per site depending on serve capabilities.

Comment: Most hosting provider support Wordpress. You can just to find provider that meet your requirement. For Managed WP hosting, take a look at WPEngine. If you are able to manage your own WP, you can just use Asphostportal, it is more cost effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many hosting providers like hostgator, bluehost offer one click script installation option in their Cpanel. You just need to login and choose what script you want to install(wordpress, drupal ...etc)